# Loads of memory used, but cannot identify where (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

This is the output to free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3850       3369        481          2         20        179
-/+ buffers/cache:       3168        681
Swap:         7628         57       7571
```

It is showing 681MB free (with cached).

top (sorted by memory use):

```
top - 13:30:16 up 10 days, 31 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 2.18, 6.54
Tasks: 143 total,   1 running, 142 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3943132 total,  3449240 used,   493892 free,    21496 buffers
KiB Swap:  7812092 total,    59320 used,  7752772 free.   183972 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
30660 deployer  20   0  170624  31132   4364 S   0.0  0.8   0:00.62 ruby
30583 whoopsie  20   0  335684   3584   2424 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 whoopsie
22772 root      20   0   23584   2412   1356 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.12 bash
    1 root      20   0   33640   1940    740 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.29 init
30737 root      20   0   25012   1732   1208 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
20987 deployer  20   0   23668   1272    772 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 bash
 2267 rabbitmq  20   0    8392   1104     32 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.92 epmd
21397 root      20   0   23484   1092    652 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 bash
21365 postfix   20   0   42768   1044    804 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 smtpd
```

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        3943132 kB
MemFree:          494660 kB
Buffers:           21304 kB
Cached:           183892 kB
SwapCached:         9904 kB
Active:            64912 kB
Inactive:         183804 kB
Active(anon):      34912 kB
Inactive(anon):    10788 kB
Active(file):      30000 kB
Inactive(file):   173016 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       7812092 kB
SwapFree:        7752720 kB
Dirty:               104 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         37492 kB
Mapped:            10748 kB
Shmem:              2172 kB
Slab:              48140 kB
SReclaimable:      26300 kB
SUnreclaim:        21840 kB
KernelStack:        1224 kB
PageTables:         8040 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9783656 kB
Committed_AS:     370152 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      347604 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359366292 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       73228 kB
DirectMap2M:     4016128 kB
```

I tried to kill all memory hungry processes and it is still showing 3168MB of used memory (excluding cached) - why? where is this memory going? how do I find out?

Comment: Try running `top -o +%MEM` to sort by memory usage

Comment: The output is already sorted by memory by running top followed by "shift+m"